# Powershell Remove Symbolic Link Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, symlink, junction

I am having issues when removing SymbolicLinks which I have created with New-Item:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\SPI -Target "C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\"
```

I need to modify the link because it has the wrong `-Target`, which should be:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\SPI -Target "C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\SPI"
```

How to remove that link and assign a new one? Alternatively, how to update the target path of the existing link?

Comment: This is not removing the link but rather replacing/updating it.  Have you tried the `-Force` parameter?

Comment: Correct, I do not know how to remove the link-  The second item is just showing what I needed it to be.

Comment: It's absolutely absurd that `Remove-Item` on a symbolic directory link attempts to recursively delete the original folder.

Answer (score 47):

Calling `Delete()` on the corresponding DirectoryInfo object should do the trick:

```
(Get-Item C:\SPI).Delete()
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\SPI -Target "C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\SPI"
```

Comment: (Get-Item C:\SPI).Delete() still works as expected: Removing the SymbolicLink and leaving the target folder intact. (Tested PS6 win10)

Comment: Thx! It also works in older versions like Power Shell 4.

Comment: Just don't use get-childitem or dir instead and delete all the files inside the folder!

Answer (score 20):

If you want to change the target path of the existing symbolic link `C:\SPI` from `"C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\"` to `"C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\SPI\"` you do not need to delete the link beforehand.  Simply including the `-Force` parameter to overwrite the link works for me in PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10 Pro v1603:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path C:\SPI -Target "C:\Users\Chino\Dropbox (Reserve Membership)\SPI" -Force
```

Answer (score 5):

No way to update the symbolic link as far as I know. Gotta use CMD to remove symbolic link and you could then re-create it using your powershell script. You would do it like this in powershell.

```
cmd /c "rmdir C:\SPI"
```

Answer (score 0):

"del" or "remove-item" works in powershell 7.