# Delete children directories in powershell including symlinks

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Currently experiencing issue, I'm currently doing this:

```
Get-ChildItem $PATH -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
  Where-Object {($_.Attributes -notmatch '\"Directory\"') -and  
              ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-12))}| 
    Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Now, it would delete fine IF I didn't have symlinks, but I do. I am getting this error:

> Remove-Item : There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point
>   At line:1 char:184
>   + ...  ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-12))}| Remove-Item -Force
>   +                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], Win32Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

I'm unable to upgrade powershell to v6. It seems to be related to:https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/621#issuecomment-289230180

Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: You could do a separate run with `|? LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'|%{$_.Delete()}` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537590/6811411)

Comment: Yeah, that was something I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This problem seems to be fixed in PS 6 (ref: https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/621)

In PS 5.1 one can work around it by using:

```
$(get-item $theSymlinkDir).Delete()
```

or as LotPings noted in the comments to the Q for this specific Foreach-Object loop:

```
|? LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'| % { $_.Delete() }
```

Comment: I would say in PS 6 they've chosen to ignore it.  I have the same problem with ntfs junction points under user profiles in windows 10.  But cmd works.

Comment: @js2010 - you mean to say it is not fixed in PS6 ?

Comment: I'm wrong.  Deleting dir symbolic links work in ps 6.  The problem I'm dealing with is more bizarre.  Reparsepoints with no target.

Answer (score 6):

Tested today on `PowerShell 7` and unfortunately the issue is still there: PowerShell cannot delete symlink.

I had to delete the directory through an elevated prompt typing `cmd /c rmdir /s /q C:\Users\Your_User_Name\Your_Folder_Name`

Comment: Gives a "the directory not empty" error for me.

Comment: Strange, try the "Force" command